# Django adding and removing form ManyToMany field: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to add users to a many to many fields in my course model buy I am getting an error:

```
Course.course_dislikes.through.objects.filter(course__course_code=code,course__course_university=university).add(request.user)
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'add'
```

My intention is to filter my Course model based on course code and add a user to like a field or remove it when the user dislikes. Now I know I cannot use get since there may be two objects with the same course code. Currently, I am trying to do this by:

```
Course.course_likes.through.objects.filter(course__course_code=code).remove(request.user)
```

I have tried with `get` but it gaves me an error that two objects with the same name exist which is understandable since get has to return one unique object. How can I achieve this withot for-loop as I cannot think of anny other method.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this without loop

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes it seems you are right there is no query that can retrieve all information at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the comment of Arakkal Abu is valid:
Here is a snipped from the official Django documentation on how to create an M2M relationship:

```
a4 = Article(headline='NASA finds intelligent life on Earth')
a4.save()
p2.article_set.add(a4)
p2.article_set.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Article: NASA finds intelligent life on Earth>]>
a4.publications.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Publication: Science News>]>
```

Not sure, if there is another way - thought about it. But could not come up with a solution. In these cases its always good to go with along the documentation.